# How to compare when two dates are within 30 days

Tags: java

I'm trying to set my form to specif logic when the two dates are within 30 days.

```
Date fromDate = form.getFromDate();
Date toDate = form.getToDate();
if(fromDate.compareTo(toDate) > 30){ // if the selected date are within one month

 }
```

I want to add like validation to be sure the selected two dates are in month rang

Comment: This becomes easier if you're using Java 8 or newer.  What version of Java are you running?

Comment: A month is not 30 days. January 13 to February 13 are within a month apart, but 31 days from each other. February 13 to March 14 are more than a month apart, but 29 days from each other (if not leap year).

Comment: Do you mean thirty generic days of 24-hours each, or fo you mean thirty calendar days?

Comment: I'm using java 8

Comment: calendar days, I want to add like validation to be sure the selected two dates are in month rang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date fromDate = form.getFromDate();
Date toDate = form.getToDate();
LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(fromDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime to= LocalDateTime.ofInstant(toDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

if(Duration.between(from, to).toDays() <= 30){
//do work
}
```

Make sure to specify the ZoneId correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Java 8 or higher, this code is ideal:

```
Instant fromInstant = fromDate.toInstant();
Instant toInstant = toDate.toInstant();
Duration duration = Duration.between(fromInstant, toInstant);
final Duration THIRTY_DAYS = Duration.ofDays(30);

if(duration.compareTo(THIRTY_DAYS) < 0) {
    //Duration is less than thirty days
} else if(duration.compareTo(THIRTY_DAYS) > 0) {
    //Duration is more than thirty days
} else {
    //Duration is exactly thirty days.... somehow....
}
```

If you need a "conceptual" month (which can vary in duration from 28-31 days), rather than an exact quantity of 30 days, this code is better:

```
//Replace with the exact time zone of these dates
//if it's not the same as the time zone of the computer running this code.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); 

LocalDate fromLocalDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(fromDate.toInstant(), zoneId);
LocalDate toLocalDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(toDate.toInstant(), zoneId);
Period period = Period.between(fromLocalDate, toLocalDate);
final Period ONE_MONTH = Period.ofMonths(1);

if(period.compareTo(ONE_MONTH) < 0) {
    //Difference is less than one month
} else if(period.compareTo(ONE_MONTH) > 0) {
    //Difference is greater than one month
} else {
    //Difference is exactly one month
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you can get the help of [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html):

To determine if the difference between your dates is 30 days use [`ChronoUnit.DAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS):

```
LocalDate from = fromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate to = fromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
if(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to) == 30L){
    // 30 days between dates
}
```

For a real month use [`ChronoUnit.MONTHS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MONTHS):

```
LocalDate from = fromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate to = toDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
if(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(from, to) == 1L){
    // 1 month between dates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at GregorianCalendar.roll(field, amount). You would convert the lesser of your two dates to a GregorianCalendar and then roll it up by 30. You can then retrieve the date value and do a straight compare.

Comment: That terrible class was outmoded years ago by the java.time classes, specifically `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score -2):

This?

```
long INTERVAL = 30L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;

long diff = Math.abs((toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()));

boolean test = diff <= INTERVAL;

if(test) {
    //....
```

Comment: Month is not always 30 days. Probably better to use different name. Otherwise I like the simplicity of this solution.

Comment: The question says: " two dates are within 30 days."

Comment: My comment was just about the variable name. It was not me who down voted it. Curious to see why it was down voted.

Comment: I'm not curious. Thank you for point the variable name issue.

Comment: Rolling your own date-time code is ill-advised when we have the excellent java.time classes at our disposal.